# ajax success не возвращается результат выполнения скрипта

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
Помогите разобраться!
В <div id="ChatBox"></div> должно выводится данные из базы не перезагружая страницу.
```

Network браузера показывает, что chatmess.php загружается, но почему-то не возвращается результат выполнения скрипта. В chatmess.php ошибок нет проверял.

---

```
<?php MessageShow(); ULogin(1);  /* 0 - страница для гостей */

if ($_POST['enter'] and $_POST['text']) {
$_POST['text'] = FormChars($_POST['text']);
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `chat`  VALUES ('', '$_POST[text]', '$_SESSION[USER_LOGIN]', NOW())");
exit(header('location: /chat'));
}
Head('Чат');
?>

<body>
     <div id="header">       <?php RegLogin()?>  </div>                                           <!-- Шапка сайта -->
     <div id="menu">         <?php Menu()?>      </div>                                           <!-- Меню -->
     <div id="advertising">                      </div>                                           <!-- Реклама -->   
     <div id="content"  style="background: url(/resource/img/menu.jpg) repeat-y #fc0;">

<div id="containerChat" >

<h1> .......... ЧАТ .......... </h1>

<div class="Page">

<div id="ChatBox"></div>                                <!-- динамически выводится в блок базы чата (chatmess.php) -->

 <br><div><form method="POST" action="/chat">           <!-- обработчик чата расположен в этом же файле (chat.php) -->
                    <textarea class="ChatMessage" name="text" placeholder="Текст сообщения" required></textarea>
                    <br><input type="submit" name="enter" value="Отправить"><input type="reset" value="Очистить">
          </form>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">  <?php Footer()?></div>                                           <!-- Низ сайта -->  

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {show(); setInterval('show()',2000);});

    function show(){  
            $.ajax({  
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'page/chatmess.php',  
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,               
                success: function(html){  
                         $('#ChatBox').html(html);  
                }  
            });  
        }       
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

chatmess.php

```
<?php 
    $Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'SELECT * FROM `chat` ORDER By `time` DESC LIMIT 50');
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Query)) {
    echo '<div class="ChatBlock"><span>'.$Row['user'].' ........ '.$Row['time'].'</span>'.$Row['message'].'</div>';}
```

### ?>

фрагмент файла index.php --- подключаем jquery-3.3.1.js

```
    function Head($p1) {
    echo '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="mailru-domain" content="Ja0YH77h5w5g4CPs" />
    <title>'.$p1.'</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" /><meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="resource/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    </head>';}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте `console.log("Success", html);` в обработчик `success` и `echo 'test-test-test';` в chatmess.php

Comment: Ни какой реакции.

Comment: никакой реакции - где? В консоли браузера что-нибудь появилось? Добавьте в ajax обработчик `error: function() { console.log("Error", this); }`.

Comment: 9chat: 60 Success. в консоли

Comment: добавил    error: function() { console.log("Error", this); }       результат        11chat:60 Success

Comment: `echo 'test-test-test';` в chatmess.php

Comment: echo 'test-test-test'; в chatmess.php   добавил. в консоле счетчик выводится и надпись Success.

Comment: в каком месте Вы это добавили? какой счетчик?

Comment: $.ajax({  
                method: 'POST',
    url: 'page/chatmess.php',  
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false, 
                success: function(html){ 
       $('#ChatBox').html(html);  
       console.log('success', html);
                }
            });  
        }

Comment: в каком месте chatmess.php Вы добавили `echo 'test-test-test';`?

Comment: <?php echo 'test-test-test'; ?> для теста пойдет.

Comment: А где подключение к бд в chatmess?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас где-то лежит другой `chatmess.php`, а Вы редактируете не тот, к которому обращается `$.ajax`.

Comment: Все проверил других нет.

Comment: Куда же тогда девается "tets-test-test"?

Answer (score 0):

Так как chatmess.php отдельный файл, пропишите в нем подключение к бд:

```
$connect=mysql_connect(
  //ваши параметры бд
);
```

Или если уже есть файл с подключением, подключите его:

```
include_once ("connection.php");
```

Comment: Запрос к серверу идет это в NetWork браузера видно. А чтение-выполнение chatmess.php не происходит.

Comment: Обкатали мой код на другом сайте (попросил товарища) все работает.